# disable product variation value woocommerce

Tags: colors, attributes, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce store where I sell screenprintings that I print by myself. I have setup a product variation called colors where I have 15 different colors. I use the same variation for all the designs I sell in the shop. When I'm out of ink for a certain color I need to disable this color (not delete) until I get the ink. I don't want to disable the color on each product and I didn't see any option to disable some colors in the attributes panel. Does anyone know how to achieve this?